# Pydev / Console : Add custom button

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using Python in Pydev.

In the bar just above the console (when in interactive mode) I would like to add a button that runs the %paste command in the console.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse and PyDev are built upon Java and 100% open source, so it is possible. However, the contribution barrier might be that advanced Eclipse-specific Java knowledge is required from you.

[Source code for the PyDev interactive console plugin is here](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/tree/development/plugins/org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console). You can edit the console UI and add your own buttons using UI tools provided by Eclipse platform.

I suggest the following steps to proceed

- Contact PyDev community and ask that you want to contribute a new feature
- Ask for further guidance how to edit the existing PyDev UI